# How to swap values of two CSS variables?

Tags: css, css-variables

Let's say I have two css variables, `control-color` and `control-color-inverse`. I want to make a `<div>` where all of the colours are inverted. But this doesn't seem to work properly:

```css
* {
  background-color: var(--control-color);
  color: var(--control-color-inverse);
}

:root {
  --control-color: gainsboro;
  --control-color-inverse: black;
}

#child {
  --control-color: var(--control-color-inverse);
  --control-color-inverse: var(--control-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>not themed</p>
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grandchild">
      <p>themed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example, in this snippet, `div#child` should have a black background with grey text. But it seems that I end up with a circular reference and it cancels out. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Try adding these lines in the parent of the div you want to apply these variables

Comment: @vaibhavkumar I updated my question with a sample; that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this

```
#child {
  background-color: var(--control-color-inverse);
  color: var(--control-color);
}
```

or you can use other variable name

```
#child {
  --child-control-color: var(--control-color-inverse);
  --child-control-color-inverse: var(--control-color);
}
```

Comment: But I want all of my elements to use a colour scheme from CSS variables. Any elements inside of `#child` would still be using the original variables, whose colours have not changed, and thus their themes would not be inverted.